# Wrapping text around 2 stacked and offset images

Tags: css, word-wrap

here is a fiddle of what I have : http://jsfiddle.net/Gwyt2/

pertinent section of code

```
    <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Animal Facilities</h3>
        <div class="lead">
            <img src="//lorempixel.com/234/156" title="" />
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesent sollicitudin, nisi sed ornare sodales, tellus enim feugiat s apien, vitae egestas sem nibh quis risus.
            <img src="//lorempixel.com/269/202" title="" />
        </div>
        <a href="#" title="Animal Facilities">Learn More ></a>
    </div>
```

pertinent css

```
#carousel img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
#carousel .carousel-indicators {
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 25px;
    left: auto;
    width: auto;
}
#carousel .carousel-indicators li {
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-width: 0;
}
#carousel .carousel-indicators li.active {
    background-color: #0498d7;
}
#carousel .carousel-caption {
    text-align: left;
}
#carousel .carousel-caption a {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#carousel .carousel-caption h3 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 3em;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #carousel .carousel-caption {
        left: 5%;
        right: 40%;
        top: 0;
    }
}
/* slide 1 */
 #carousel .carousel-caption img:first-of-type {
    float: right;
    width: 40%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
#carousel .carousel-caption img:last-of-type {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20%;
    top: 51%;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 40%;
    height: auto;
}
```

What I am trying to do is have text wrap around 2 images separately, the images are slightly offset so the text should indent when it hits the lower image

You will notice now that it will write over the lower image

what I want to do

```
****************** --------
****************** |      |
****************** |      |
****************** |      |
****************** |      |
****************** |      |
************* --------    |
************* |      |-----
************* |      |
************* |      |
************* |      |
************* --------
```

Comment: You currently cannot do this with CSS. Content cannot avoid elements with `position:absolute` because they are taken out of the stacking order. Perhaps you could do some funny trick with both images having `float:right` and use negative margins, but I have my doubts. CSS regions are what you need for this, but I am afraid they are not a viable option yet

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the text around 2 stacked images with a little trick in margins:

```
#carousel .carousel-caption img:first-of-type {
    float: right;
    width: 40%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 10px -5% 0;
}
#carousel .carousel-caption img:last-of-type {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20%;
    top: 51%;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 40%;
    height: auto;
}
```

You need to change the HTML, the text must be after the images.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gwyt2/1/)

What I am not able to figure is how to set the second image under the first one (z-index won't work).

Are your images always of the same size ?

Comment: I will have to try this Monday from work.  The images will be of a set height/width once they are decided on, but currently these numbers are not set at the moment